# Rails 2.3 caching by time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I would like to cache my fragment page in my rails application by time.

I found this plugin to do this => [ici](http://code.google.com/p/timedcachedfragment/) but any download is available.

I searched in the rails doc but I don't found how to cache my fragment by time.

Are you know another plugin to do this or another method to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a time-based cache key is quite simple.
[Here's an example](http://gist.github.com/308598).

Now in your app you can write

```
<% cache :expires => CacheKey.expirable(:hour) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If you want a more accurate control (for example 5.minutes instead of simply 1 minute), you can easily adapt the module in order to dynamically generate the cache key reading the time value passed as parameter.

An other approach is to check the last-modified time of the cache file. [Here's a plugin](http://github.com/adamsalter/filestore_expires_in-plugin).